# How to generate the "WebKitFormBoundaries" in POST request to upload the csv file in RestAPI (robot framework)

Tags: python-3.x, rest, csv, robotframework

I have tried through the UI and rest API. In UI, the WebKitFormBoundaries are generating , when I tried same through the rest API, the its not generating in payload

**The UI request:**

Headers

```
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: <connection>
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary<45chars>
token: <token>
id: <id>
```

payload( the csv file )

```
------WebKitFormBoundary<45chars>
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="file.csv"
Content-Type: text/csv

R,FN,SE
,5501,,

------WebKitFormBoundary<45chars>--
```

Response: 200 success

**The API request:**
headers=

```
{'Content-Length': '526',
 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 
'Token': u'<token>', 
'Accept': '*/*',
 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.10.0',
 'Connection': '<connection>', 
'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data;
 boundary=<45chars>',
 'ClientID': '<Id>'}
```

payload

```
body=--<45chars>
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="<file>"; filename="<filename>"
R,FN,SE
,5501,,

--<45chars>--
```

Response is error code 500
Here in the Rest API request the **WebKitFormBoundary** not generating, what I am missing in my post request, any one please help me.

Thanks in Advance